For $n\le k!$, Adjacent-vertex-distinguishing-total-coloring using at most $\chi'(G)+k+1$ exists
Recently, I'm studying probabilistic methods in graph theory, and some practice problem was to prove that,
for any $n$-vertex graph $G$ with $k!\ge n$, there exists a adjacent-vertex-distinguishing-total-coloring of $G$  using at most $\chi'(G)+k+1$ colors.
Here, adjacent-vertex-distinguishing-total-coloring is a coloring for vertices and edges in a graph such that there aren't two objects having same color, and intersects or adjacent.
I tried to solve this using what I learned(such as local lemma, alteration method), but it doesn't works as well. Is there any proofs-or references for this problem?

Please give definition and context.

What happens if you color the edges in $\chi'(G)$ colors and then assign $k+1$ colors to the vertices randomly? Can you bound the expectation of "bad" events?
